# how to calculate on the fly with awk using previous and next line values

Tags: awk

How can I read values with awk and use the previous values with the next values to calculate and add it to additional column in each line:

example test.log:

```
$1         $2         $3        $4        $5        $6
2018/02/21 14:00:24   911       848       958       719
2018/02/21 14:00:34   978       848       998       966
```

with the 7th column:

```
$1         $2         $3        $4        $5        $6        $7
2018/02/21 14:00:24   911       848       958       719       0.0
2018/02/21 14:00:34   978       848       998       966       0.45
```

The 7th column should be calculated by the below function:

```
(($3-prev3)+($5-prev5))/240 = ((978-911)+(998-958))/240
```

The first line in the log file can only have 0.0 for the 7th column!

My problem is that I would like to add the 7th column on the fly into the log file and not after the logging is finished as printout only:

```
awk '{a=$3;b=$5;getline;print(($3-a)+($5-b))/240}' test.log
```

How can i do that?
Is there a possibility to be at the current line and have stored in variables of the previous values?

The one-liner that creates the log file with the 6 columns that should on the fly add the 7th column with the above calculation:

```
while true; do echo `date +"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"` "#" `echo $RANDOM` "#" `echo $RANDOM` "#" `echo $RANDOM` "#" `echo $RANDOM` | awk -F# '{printf "%-20s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'>>test.log; sleep 10; done
```

This try did not work also since it is always adding 0 at the 7th column:

```
awk -F# '{a=$3;b=$5;printf "%-20s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,(($3-a)+($5-b))/240}'
```

I assume that a,b has the same values as $3 & $5 and not the previous values!

test.log:

```
2018/02/22 03:37:12   10241           29132           3358            17816          0
2018/02/22 03:37:17   12464           21254           16716           10024          0
```

One solution with awk script, but it is not on the fly solution would be:

```
awk '{a=$3;b=$5;getline;print(($3-a)+($5-b))/240}' test.log
```

Which will give only the calculation as output!

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if you can create a tool that modifies the file it is reading while that file is also being written to by some other process?

Comment: You'd have to pipe the output through awk to do that. 
`your-log-producer | awk '[your calculations]' > test.log`

Comment: Yes, @EdMorton, correct i would need some additional awk line or other tool to modify the original log file with the calculation at the 7th column. I will add some more information about the the one-liner that creates the log file with the numbers!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==1{
                         print $0, "$7"; 
                         next
                 }
                 p3!=""{
                         n=(($3-p3)+($5-p5))/240
                 }
                 {
                     p3=$3; 
                     p5=$5; 
                     print $0,n+0
                 }
                ' infile
```

Input:

```
$ cat infile
$1         $2         $3        $4        $5        $6
2018/02/21 14:00:24   911       848       958       719
2018/02/21 14:00:34   978       848       998       966
```

Output:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==1{print $0, "$7"; next}p3!=""{n=(($3-p3)+($5-p5))/240}{p3=$3; p5=$5; print $0,n+0}' infile
$1         $2         $3        $4        $5        $6  $7
2018/02/21 14:00:24   911       848       958       719 0
2018/02/21 14:00:34   978       848       998       966 0.445833
```

Comment: I actually have a awk script to get the calculation by parsing the log file, but it is not on the fly like your answer! See my solution for this in my question.